# What's going on with this preg_match?

Tags: php, regex

```
      $var = 3;
        if ($cleanvar = preg_match('/^[0-9]{0,2}$/', $var)) 
            {
                echo $cleanvar; echo $var; exit();
            }
        else
              . . .
```

Strange output. This is causing my `cleanvar` to echo `1` and `var` still echo's `3`. Why is this happening? The point of this `regex` is to only match whole numbers, as 1 or 2 digits. e.g.( 1, 2, 4, 38, 24)

Is their an issue in my Regex? Or what is causing this odd behavior?

Comment: It's probably worth noting that this pattern will match empty string.

Comment: @wiseguy no it does not. assuming you mean '' as empty string. It returns false

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Start of subject, zero digits, end of subject. [working example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YCGtLH)

Comment: @wiseguy Strange - I ran the same test when I read your comment on my actual code and it returns 0 for the same input

Comment: You are using a number (`$var = 3`) where the target _string_ is called for. See: `preg_match()` syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$cleanvar` is just true or false.  You're looking for a number between 0 and 2 digits in length (from the beginning to the end of the string, so no other characters are allowed).

EDIT: it returns 1 if matched, 0 if not.

See this for more information: https://www.php.net/preg_match

Comment: Also, the match is expecting to find the numbers on a line by themselves.  Not sure if that is the intent, but may cause misses if the real data contains more than the bare number.

Comment: @jheddings, thanks I updated my answer to include what you said.  It won't allow any other characters in the match.

Comment: Do you guy think down-voting this question is just? Some schmuck likes down voting me as if it is their job. Anyway thanks again for the quick answer and if you don't agree with the down-vote. Please vote me up. Thanks again guys!

Comment: No issue with the question.  It is well stated and looking for a specific answer.

Comment: The code/function in question does exactly what the documentation says it should do. "does not show research effort" / "not useful"

Answer (score 0):

`$var` should be followed by an array if you want it set. You might wish to change to `{1,2}` if matching >=1.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is correct, and it is matching correct. Just that preg_match returns 1 if you get a match and 0 if it doesn't. See the [documentation.](https://www.php.net/preg_match)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to validate an input value, you only need look at the return of `preg_match`.  Using the `+` operator matches "one or more of the preceding element."

```
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $var)) {
    // we matched a number only, so we know $var is clean
} else {
}
```

If you need to extract a number from an input field, you can use capture groups:

```
if (preg_match('/([0-9]+)/', $var, $matches)) {
    $num = $matches[1];
} else {
}
```

Note that this does not match the entire input, but will return on the first number it finds in the input `$var`.